# Enable TLS 1.2 for ldap_* functions in PHP 5.3

Tags: php, ldap, tls1.2

Our code base connects to our Active Directory through the `ldap_*` functions. I just learned this morning that they're connecting to our AD over TLS 1.0.

**Question 1**: Is there a way to force the `ldap_*` functions to connect over TLS 1.2?

Other info:

- Windows 2012 R2
- PHP 5.3
- IIS 8.5

I've tried googling stuff like "[enable "tls 1.2" ldap php](https://www.google.com/search?q=enable+"tls+1.2"+ldap+php)," "["tls 1.2" ldap php](https://www.google.com/search?q="tls+1.2"+ldap+php)," "[ldap php functions support tls 1.2](https://www.google.com/search?q=ldap+php+functions+support+tls+1.2)" and results have been unhelpful. I've found comments on three locations that say that [Windows 2012 R2 doesn't support TLS 1.2 through LDAPS](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-bind.php#118543) and to **disable** TLS 1.2, but ... that's the opposite of what I want, and so far there have been no issues with *not* specifically disabling TLS 1.2 in the code base.

**Followup Question**: Do the `ldap_*` functions still not support TLS 1.2 on Windows 2012 R2 with PHP?

Answer (score 0):

I talked to a friend who is much more knowledgeable about security than I.

The scope of my question was too narrow and the problem comes from the version of PHP I am on.

In order for PHP to securely connect to Active Directory, it uses the OpenSSL library. TLS 1.1/1.2 support in OpenSSL came in v1.0.1. PHP 5.3 comes with v0.9.8.

My friend gave me a suggestion of faking TLS 1.1 and forcing the ldap functions to use that, like this:

```
define('LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_PROTOCOL_MIN', 24583);
define('LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_PROTOCOL_SSL2', 512);
define('LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_PROTOCOL_SSL3', 768);
define('LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_PROTOCOL_TLS1_0', 769);
define('LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_PROTOCOL_TLS1_1', 770);
define('LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_PROTOCOL_TLS1_2', 771);
```

and

```
ldap_set_option($handler, LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_PROTOCOL_MIN, LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_PROTOCOL_TLS1_1);
```

But this did not work for me.

I attempted to try using newer versions of OpenSSL with 5.3, but these did not work either.  It seems that truly the only solution is updating to a newer version of PHP, minimum of 5.6.

There's a possibility of using a third-party library, but that is a can of worms I chose not to open.

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: @RodneySalcedo Nope, and I have since changed jobs, so no longer a priority of mine. I think at the time, I had refocused on trying to refactor the codebase to support a newer version of PHP.

Comment: Thinking about this again, it might be possible to compile PHP 5.3 _with_ OpenSSL v1.0.1 but there might be unforeseen complications. This possibility depends on the comfort level of the dev with compiling php-src, and willingness/skill-level to resolve problems. But at that point, it may just be better to update the code base to support a newer version of PHP.

Comment: Yes, It is best to upgrade everything you can